# OpenSSL::PKey::RSA Create key without passphrase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, rsa

I Created a keys pair using:

```
private def new_keys
    key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new 2048
    type = key.public_key.ssh_type
    data = [key.public_key.to_blob].pack('m0')
    public_key_openssh_format = "#{type} #{data}"
    {
      :private => key.to_pem,
      :public => public_key_openssh_format,
    }
end
```

Next, I exported both public and private key to files.
When I try to use the public key it prompts me for passphrase, which I didn't add.

As per documentation: [A pass_phrase can be used to decrypt the key. If none is given OpenSSL will prompt for the pass phrase.](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKey/RSA.html#new-method). But I've run it in a rails process, so I'm not sure what's the behavior.

Comment: do you intend t deal with SSL keys (as your code and title suggest) or ssh keys (as you write in your text)? Also, how exactly are you exporting the key? Please show that code.

Comment: @HolgerJust I meant to generate ssh keys pair, I updated the code